# Configure Apple Mobile Access Server for iPhones, iPads and Macs

Tags: mac-osx, osx-snow-leopard, ipad

I successfully configured [Mobile Access Server](http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/features/mobile-access.html) on Mac OS X Server 10.6, but now, how do I configure Macs, iPhones and iPads I'm in charge of ?
How can these machines access all the services provided by the Mobile Access Server ?

I can't find anything useful on the web concerning the client setup.

Is there any '1-click configuration' that would setup iCal, Addresses and Mail at once on a machine like the MobileMe setup does ?
Or do I have to manually configure each services on each machines ?

I gave a look at the [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL851) but it cannot configure Macs, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

After a long search myself, I've found a couple of videos on lynda.com Snow Leopard new features, but you have to be a member (which luckily I was):

http://www.lynda.com/home/DisplayCourse.aspx?lpk2=56405

1. Configure MA Services to use SSL externally but not regular non-SSL ports, use the non-SSL ports AB-8800, iCAL= 800. You need to connect your client apps (iCAL, AB etc) with accounts using the CalDAV, Card DAV options. When out of the office, you visit the SSL 'Home page' seen on Apple's MA page for OSX:

"https://server.domain.com/secure_proxy_login.php?https://server.domain.com/"

(sorry can't post images to show you what it looks like)

and login for website, or launch your app AB, iCAL and reconfigure your client settings to use SSL once logged into the MAN page.

Still having problems myself getting this Homepage up on my server, but at least I know what I'm shooting for now!

Good luck